# How to disable pinch scale in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, pinch

I use UIImagePickerController to take photos in my ios app. But I don't want the camera view to scale when pinch gesture occur. what can I do? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an overlay that captures the touches:

```
   picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
   [picker setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];
   [picker setShowsCameraControls:NO];
   [picker setDelegate:self];
   [self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

Comment: I did this like your code, But the picker can still get touches, it scale all the same

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disabled interaction on the picker's view.

```
picker.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Value of type 'UIImagePickerController' has no member 'userInteractionEnabled'

Comment: Updated.  Sorry forgot its a view controller.   disable its view.